# How to check if bool is false in a loop

Tags: c#, class, loops, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to loop through an array of classes. The class has two variables: a transform and a bool.

I want to loop through this in another script to see if that current position is occupied and if so the bool occupied will be set to true.

How can I go about doing this?

```
 public Positions[] PosInObect = new Positions[1];

 [System.Serializable]
 public class Positions
 {
     public Transform pos;
     public bool isFilled;
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect.Length; i++) 
 {

 }
```

Comment: The very first sentence in the description of the tag [tag:Unity] is *"DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)!!"*

Comment: The code you show has an array of size one, not much looping required. :)

Comment: i just used 1 for testing as the object in question does not have multiple seats later on their will be more than one object that the player can use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you can just access the element at the relevant index, and then check the field value:

```
 if (TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect[i].isFilled)
```

However, if you don't need the index, I'd recommend using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var position in TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect)
{
    if (position.isFilled)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And if you *do* need the position, I'd use a local variable to fetch the array once first:

```
var positions = TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect;
for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
{
    if (positions[i].isFilled)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend using properties instead of public fields, and following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: ok ive gotta wait 3 mins before i can accept this but this is perfect thanks so much you have taught me allot this is very useful

Comment: one quick question tho how can i make positions public? what variable type would i use

Comment: so that i can acces in another class

Comment: @pvtctrlalt: But what are you asking about making public? You've currently shown everything *as* public...

Comment: no i mean this bit var positions = TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect; how can i make this usable in other  functions as at the moment it is local

Comment: because what i want to do it later on call the isoccupied and turn it to false

Comment: @pvtctrlalt: Okay, none of that is really clear to me, but it sounds like you're sorted now...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a foreach loop. You will be still able to access the variables from that class instance.

```
foreach(Positions pos in TheObject.GetComponent<GetInObject>().PosInObect)
{
    if(pos.isFilled)
    {
       //Do something
    }
}
```